# count() on collection takes very long with Spring Data but not with MongoShell

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring I load a pagable of a collection (1 million records) which takes very long. In the logs I can see that the query for count is taking over 10 seconds:

```
gameRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.by("played").descending())
```

Logs:

> Executing count: {} in collection: game **<- Takes 10 Seconds!!**

When I execute the count command via Mongo Shell it appears instant:

```
db.game.count(); // -> 1332751
```

What is the reason that it takes so long with Spring Data?

Comment: Are you actually using `count` in Spring Data? Your example shows that you're using `findAll`. These are completely different methods.

Comment: I am using the findAll() which returns a page, containing the first 10 records and the total count of elements. Do deliver this Spring Data has to execute the count command

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of counting things in databases:

- Perform the query that calculates the exact set, then look at how many results were found.
- Record the size of collections/tables in metadata.

The second approach provides an approximate count - it's generally close to the real count but often isn't exactly correct. Because retrieving this count doesn't require querying the stored documents, it is very fast.

The shell helper uses the approximate count. I assume your paginated query uses the accurate count.

Comment: But event when I query like this in mongo shell: gameRepository.findAll(...).size(); the result appears in under a second for indexed fields and in Spring data I do not event have filter inside the findAll method

Answer (score 0):

There is `long count();` method in `JpaRepository` (to count total entity set) and `long count(Specification<T> spec)` method in `JpaSpecificationExecutor` (to count some filtered subset).

You should use them instead of loading collection into memory

```
size = gameRepository.count();
```

is much more efficient than

```
size = gameRepository.findAll(...).size();
```

because they are translated to `SELECT COUNT(...)` native SQL queries.

Comment: gameRepository.findAll(...).size(); -> This command also is very fast in MongoDB event with a query it takes only like under a second